# Clear html5 sessionStorage across http/https

Tags: html, cross-domain, session-storage

I have two websites http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com. I am using HTML5 session storage to store user preferences.
A user arrives at http://www.example.com and I load some default settings via ajax. 
They browse to a page requiring login and are sent to https://www.example.com/login.html
After they are done logging in they are sent back to http://www.example.com where because they are now logged in I should fetch new settings from the server. The trouble is that http and https are different origins and can't share session storage.

**Things I've tried that don't work:**
Loading a page http://www.example.com/clearSession.html in an iframe that just runs sessionStorage.removeItem('key') to clear my data, but it seems that this has it's own browsing context so it doesn't work.

**Things I've tried that work but I'm not wanting to use:**
Using a cookie. This works great because http and https can share cookies but this means all my user settings get sent to the server with every resource request. This is usually about 4k but could be up to 1MB of data. No I can't host my resources on a different domain.

Don't cache the settings and just make the request every time to get the settings. I am doing this on older browsers as they don't support session storage but it slows down the page load and puts extra load on my database.

Comment: Why do you need to load default settings before they login?  Why not just assume if there are no settings present that the default ones apply?

Comment: It's mostly about determining if I am logged in or not and being able to clear the settings when they log out.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how we have solved this problem, but it doesn't involve local sessionStorage.  We use a server-side session to store the user's login data (username, ID, etc.) after they have been to our authentication server and back.  Before they are authenticated you could still collect preference data from them by using AJAX to report these preferences back to a web service on the server that can store it in the server's session scope.  This would break the RESTful model, however, because it would assume the use of server side sessions.  That would depend on your server language and how you have your web services set up.

I think you will always bump into that origin problem because that is a restriction designed into local storage in general.

Comment: Trouble with storing everything server side is that I need to request it and I'm trying to build a rich application without any control of the page I'm building the application on.

Answer (score -2):

Switch everything to https, its a standard now.

Comment: This isn't useful. The software I was interfacing with doesn't support https.